# Parse iOS SDK: Delete objects - [self loadObjects] does not exist

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

The following links...

[ONE](https://parse.com/questions/delete-row-from-pfquerytableviewcontroller)

[TWO](https://www.parse.com/questions/delete-row-animated-from-pfquerytableviewcontroller)

[THREE](https://www.parse.com/questions/swipe-to-delete-row-from-pfquerytableviewcontroller)

all tell me to call [self loadObjects] after I delete an object.

Question 1: What is it supposed to do?

Question 2: Why does it not exist? (when I try to type it out 'intellicode' does not pick it up and tells me to delete it if I type it out myself)

Question 3: How do I refresh my PFQueryTableViewController after I delete an object to where it looks professional?

Answer (score 3):

Right out of the official Parse.com [PFQueryTableViewController Class Reference](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/loadObjects) for the `loadObjects` method: 
`Clears the table and loads the first page of objects.`

Import `<Parse/Parse.h>` in your controller if XCode tells you the `loadObjects` method does not exist, and be sure that your controller is actually a `PFQueryTableViewController`.